# Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio from breaking on exceptions in a specific method?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception, visual-studio-debugging

I know I can control the way Visual Studio handles exceptions according to their type and to the fact that they're eventually caught using the "Exception" dialog.

However, I've got a library that's internally throwing (and catching) an  `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception when I'm calling a specific method. The exception is thrown (and caught by the library) maybe 1% of the time, but I'm calling this method a lot. The editor says it's by design (and indeed, the design they've chosen makes sense).

The thing is that I don't want Visual Studio to break each time the exception is thrown.

- I don't want to stop breaking on `ArgumentOutOfRange` exceptions, as I may have some in my code and want to break on those.
- I don't want to enable "just my code" debugging because I'm concerned about the exceptions thrown outside of my code (notably for performance reasons)

Is there a way to achieve this? I've been looking into attributes (such as `DebuggerStepThrough`), but haven't find something adequate yet.

Any hints on how to do this ?

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420390/dont-stop-debugger-at-that-exception-when-its-thrown-and-caught), the `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute should be your friend. However, it seems you might not be able to modify the third-party library directly...

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644780/visual-studio-debugging-ignore-exception-in-one-place-while-breaking-at-it-else) seem to indicate that it's not possible. Although I'm not sure what you're accomplishing by breaking on exceptions raised by external code. How are you *fixing* them if you don't have the ability to modify the source code? This is a classic example of why it's really bad practice to use exceptions for flow control. [Here's a library designer who has made exactly this mistake.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541116/)

Comment: Didn't get too much attention in OzCode: http://ozcode.userecho.com/topics/362-add-feature-to-ignore-an-exception-thrown-breakpoint-on-a-specific-line-from-the-quickaction-menu/

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want to enable "just my code" debugging

Yeah, stop there right now.  That is *exactly* the feature you need to not get the unwanted debugger breaks.  If you don't want to know about somebody else's crappy code then flip that checkbox back on.

This invariably goes off the rails when programmers use exceptions for flow control.  A very common crime.  It takes *two* of them to turn that into a mess that turns a debugging session into a very tedious click nightmare.  When you need the debugger feature that breaks on the first-chance exception then you basically lost if somebody else needed that as well.

Everybody hopes that they can magically use the [DebuggerNonUserCode] or [DebuggerHidden] or [DebuggerStepThrough] attributes to make that problem disappear.  It doesn't.  The other programmer did not think his code was unimportant enough to deserve those attributes.  And, well, it wasn't because there's always a bug hidden in code that uses try/catch-em-all code.  Pokémon code.

So Microsoft had to find another way to help programmers deal with crappy library code.  They did.  Tick that checkbox, bam, solved.  Nothing you can do about that crappy code anyway, other than sending a nasty-gram to the author.  Don't let us or Microsoft slow you down doing that as well, y'all have to get along to create a product that people like to use.

Comment: Maybe I haven't made my point clear. The case is not trying to cover up exceptions but instead to make the Visual Studio debugger to behave reasonably by default without config changes. Here is an example. We have an app with custom logging, part of the custom logging in another project in the solution has code to post logging data to an HTTP endpoint. The HTTP API throws exceptions when it fails, that is ok we wrap it with Polly to handle these and retry however because we own this code Visual Studio will break on that line every time! In this case we have truely handled the exception.

Comment: In this case, the devs on the team will continue to comment out the logging code due to intermittent failures and annoyances in Visual Studio breaking on the handled exception.

Comment: No real idea what you are talking about.  Polly?  Why does the debugger stop when it is handled?  I answered the question that was asked, does not seem to have much to do with yours.  Consider posting your own question, post a comment under this question to link it.

Comment: @HansPassant Polly https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly is an exception- and transient-fault-handling library, under the stewardship of the Dot Net Foundation: https://dotnetfoundation.org/blog/welcome-polly

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not possible in visual studio but it certainly is in WinDbg. 
See for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/08/24/managed-debugging-with-windbg-breaking-on-an-exception-part-1.aspx

On a side note it seems that starting with visual studio 2010 you can load and use WinDbg extension DLLs directly providing aditional functionality (including possibly the one that  you need) but I haven't tried this yet - see for example http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=648

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use [Concord](https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples), the debug engine that ships with Visual Studio (starting with version 2012). It's quite extensible through a nice managed API (and deployable using vsix technology), but it's not fully documented.

Concord has the concept of debug monitors, that we can hook using the [IDkmDebugMonitorExceptionNotification Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.debugger.componentinterfaces.idkmdebugmonitorexceptionnotification.aspx)

The cool thing is this interface can monitor *all exceptions* thrown. It can also "suppress" any detected exception event, which is exactly what we need.

What I suggest is to start with the [Hello World](https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Hello-World-Sample) sample: . Download it, and make sure it runs as expected for you.

Now, just modify `HelloWorld.vsdconfigxml` like this:

```
<!--TODO: If you copy the sample, ensure to regenerate the GUID in this file -->

<!-- 1. change component level to something higher than 40500 -->
<ManagedComponent
  ComponentId="51736b11-9fb4-4b6d-8aca-a10a2b7ae768"
  ComponentLevel="40501"
  AssemblyName="HelloWorld">

  <!-- 2. change class full name to HelloWorld.ExceptionHandler, for example -->
  <Class Name="HelloWorld.ExceptionHandler">
    <Implements>
      <InterfaceGroup>
        <NoFilter/>
        <!-- 3. change supported interface -->
        <Interface Name="IDkmDebugMonitorExceptionNotification"/>
      </InterfaceGroup>
    </Implements>
  </Class>

</ManagedComponent>
```

Then, just create an `ExceptionHandler.cs` class and put something like this in there:

```
public class ExceptionHandler : IDkmDebugMonitorExceptionNotification
{
    private bool _unhandledDetected;

    // we're being called!
    public void OnDebugMonitorException(DkmExceptionInformation exception, DkmWorkList workList, DkmEventDescriptorS eventDescriptor)
    {
        if (_unhandledDetected)
        {
            // this will cause the program to terminate
            eventDescriptor.Suppress();
            return;
        }

        if (exception.ProcessingStage.HasFlag(DkmExceptionProcessingStage.Unhandled))
        {
            _unhandledDetected = true;
        }
        else if (exception.ProcessingStage.HasFlag(DkmExceptionProcessingStage.Thrown))
        {
            if (SuppressException(exception))
            {
                eventDescriptor.Suppress();
            }
        }
    }

    // should we suppress a thrown (1st chance) exception?
    private bool SuppressException(DkmExceptionInformation exception)
    {
        // implement any custom logic in here, for example use the exception's name
        if (exception.Name == typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException).FullName)
        {
            // for example, use the module (assembly) name
            var clrAddress = (DkmClrInstructionAddress)exception.InstructionAddress;
            var clrModule = clrAddress.ModuleInstance;
            if (clrModule.Name == "TheUglyOne.dll")
                return true; // we don't want this one!
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When you run the project, you should see *all* exceptions being monitored (regardless of your 'just my code' and/or exception triggers settings), so what you just need to do is implement some logic to suppress the ones you really don't want to see. I've not checked but I suppose you could build your logic using custom attributes as the Dkm classes provide quite a lot of .NET metadata information.

Note: as you can see, there is some trickery to make sure the program will terminate normally.