# Visual Studio 2013 catching unhandled exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception, visual-studio-2013

Some days ago our new Visual Studio 2013 copy was sent to us. 
I was working with 2010 before, and after working with 2013 for a couple of days, I really like it, but now I've found something really annoying. Have a look:
[image]

Well, my Visual Studio is in german language, but I think you can get what is happening.
What I am wondering is why VS says I've got an unhandled exception. What other than putting a try catch around this I can do to handle the exception?

This is just an example. My real code is a bit more complex, and the try/catch is located some levels above this piece of code.

I can not remember VS2010 behaving like this.

I had a look in the exceptions settings, but I did not change anything there, so I'm using default settings:
[image]

What I am wondering is why VS deals with this code as if it were unhandled, when as you can see it is not. That's why I do not want to change anything in my exceptions settings. Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: `activateCommunication` seems to be a method you've written, have tried to F11 (inside step by step) into this method to see if the `IOException` occurs in this method ?

Comment: Thanks to somebody for putting in the pictures instead of the links, and correcting my english ;-).

Comment: @AlexB: Yes activateCommunication() ist a self written method by my college. It comes from another dll with no debug information, so stepping in is not possible at this point. But I can tell you: yes the IOExceptions ist thrown by the method, because I disconnected my SerialDevice from my PC to test this situation. There is some code to handle this situation, running my App standalone from filesystem, instead from VS, the exception is caught and handled by a MessageBox. So there is no reason for VS to stop right here :(

Comment: @foxtrott79: Try posting the question on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's helping you. At runtime you would get the expected result ie. it will go to the catch block.

Disable all exceptions in the options and VS will ignore all your exceptions and let the code catch them.

**EDIT :**

You should expand the lists as they will contain checked items even if the parent/group checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: The OP says (and shows) that the option to break on handled exceptions is already disabled, and the OP (presumably) does want to break on unhandled exceptions. So the options are already what they should be, I think.

Comment: If you expand the lists you will see that it's not the case.

Comment: Don't tell me, tell the OP by putting that in your answer! :) If you're right (and you may well be), that seems to me like it's exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Alex: Well, as my code has some line of code for handling the exceptions i do not understand why VS breaks. I thought VS only stopps when an unhandled exceptions occurs. By unchecking IOException in the dialog, VS will never stopp again, when a real unhandled IOExceptions occurs?

Comment: Yep. The setting is 'global'. It will ignore the exception from then onwards.

Answer (score 1):

so i tried Alex his hint, to uncheck the Exception in the dialog.

After unchecking the Exception my code acted like it runs outside the VS debugger.
But i was not happy with the statement

> The setting is 'global'. It will ignore the exception from then onwards

So I went on with some researches.
I put some unhandled IOException throwing in my code. VS broke at the line of throwing the exception, what i was wondering about, because i unchecked the said point. Watching VS dialogs i figured out that they were not completly the same, they have a smal difference.

One said (as my VS is in german i transalted it to english by myself, maybe the text is quite a bit different in real): **IOException was not handled** - this is the unhandled IOException after unchecking the item at the Exception dialog.

The other said (translated by myself again): **IOException was not handled by usercode** - this while the item is checked in Exception-dialog.

So what is the difference between code and usercode?

I went to google for some research, i found two very importand sites. First explains the meaning of the ExceptionDialog. I do not quote anything, because all informations on this site are notable.

[ExceptionDialog explained](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2008/12/31/exceptions-dialog-explained-or-what-does-user-unhandled-mean.aspx)

Now let us know how VS is detecting usercode. Therefore i found the secound site:

[usercode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616715/what-does-visual-studio-consider-user-code)

With all these informations i did these experiments:

1. Delte .pdb file of the dll containing activateCommunication() -> VS did not break
2. Put pdb back again, unchecked "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" -> VS did not break

Well, it is a bit more clear now. What i am still wondering is why with hosting process enabled, VS breaks, even if i have handling code. Maybe there is some debugCode around calling my method that might be seen as the "system code" mentioned on website one!?!?

Well, thats what i found out.

Greetings
Ronny

Comment: Interesting. However the .pdb trick is not really a trick since without the .pdb file vs has no info about where the BP's are. As far as I know.