# Visual Studio debugger stepping into non user code on azure functions projects

Tags: c#, debugging, azure-functions, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio debugger stepping into non-user code on Azure functions projects.

- Just my code is checked.
- Reinstalled visual studio.
- Resetted my whole windows machine.
- My azure functions projects are currently not debuggable due to this annoying dialog in stepping into azure function assembly code.
- Github issue [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1268)
- Developer community [Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/632127/visual-studio-debugger-stepping-into-non-user-code.html)

[image: Annoying dialog]

[image: Annoying tab]

[image: Library code]

[image: Not my user code, this is wrong!!!]

Comment: Hi friend, is this issue reproducible in new project. If so, you can share a simple sample or directly report this issue to Product Team by the way suggested in my answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Its reproducible on new projects.
Thank you friend.

Comment: After reporting this issue in VS, you can share the link here and members interested in it can vote for it can follow the situation.

Comment: Added github and Developer community link

Comment: See the links in my update, the team is now aware of this issue and they will  release the updated packages soon. Sorry for the inconvenience before the next fix :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think maybe this's one issue about those assemblies. See the Modules Window and you can find the debugger recognize them as **User Code**!

I think that's why it will try to step into them when you've enabled `Just My Code` because the debugger thinks those functions are part of User Code. See [answer from Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617406/10910450) and you may get some help about why the debugger recognize them as `User Code`.

So it's clear if debugger recognize User Code by the rule: `No optimization + debug symbols=User Code`, then those assemblies from those folder are recognized as User code, and when you step into them, the error occurs.

**Suggestion:**

So you may have to use `step over(F10)` for those Azure functions, and `step into(F11)` for the real user-code of yours. And if this issue is reproducible in new Azure projects, I suggest you `Go Help menu=>Send Feedback=>Report the problem` to report this issue to Product Team.

**Update1:**

Now the team in Github is tracking this issue and the updated packages will release soon.

See [Debugging Options: "Enable Just My Code" ignored for Durable Functions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/872) and [Ensure packages are built in release mode](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2261).