# How to prevent Visual Studio from breaking on exception thrown in SignalR hub?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I am developing a SignalR application and when something wrong happens during a SignalR call from client, I would like to propagate the exception back to the client. However, instead of sending the exception right back to the client, Visual Studio breaks on:

```
HubException was unhandled by user code
```

If I hit F5 to continue, the exception correctly propagates back to the client.

Is there a way to teach Visual Studio to just ignore certain classes of exceptions during hub execution?

This solution does not work - it catches other exceptions, but VS still breaks on the HubException:
[How to NOT breaking on an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833498/how-to-not-breaking-on-an-exception)

Comment: Check to see if you've got break on exception for that type... Ctrl+Alt+E to launch dialogue. If so turn it off. Let me know if that's the issue and I'll add as an answer

Comment: Ian, thanks, it works, but somebody has already posted the right answer a few seconds before you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in a code window pres <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> to open the Exceptions window -> Add -> enter HubException and uncheck **Thrown** and **User-unhandeled**

[image]