# Visual Studio C# - Don't break for any exception at this line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, debugging

I have code that frequently throws an `InvalidOperationException`. In this specific case, the exception is actually OK and I don't want the debugger to break when it gets thrown. However, I can't disable all `InvalidOperationException` breaks because that's just a bad idea.

Supposedly the `DebuggerStepThrough` or `DebuggerHidden` attributes are what I need, but the exception bubbles up and ignores the `try` block - the debugger breaks anyways.

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The debugger breaks at this line.
        // Ideally it should continue execution.
        var x = TestFunc();
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden]
    private static bool TestFunc()
    {
        try
        {
            // The actual code is third-party; I can't control the exception.
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Related issues:

[How to NOT breaking on an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833498/how-to-not-breaking-on-an-exception)
(This doesn't work because there is no way to pinpoint where the exception has come from. The stack trace only points to the third party code, not my calling code.)

[Don't stop debugger at THAT exception when it's thrown and caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420390/dont-stop-debugger-at-that-exception-when-its-thrown-and-caught)
(This results in the aforementioned bubbling and circumvention.)

Using VS 2022

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you're only trying to ignore `InvalidOperationException` exceptions, then that should be specified as: `catch (InvalidOperationException)`

Comment: Have you tried the answer to the first related issue you linked? That seems very promising.

Comment: @RufusL I have. Unfortunately, there is no way to see if the calling method has a `System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden` attribute or similar for handling. The exception only has a stack trace from the third party code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible in Visual Studio. You either tell it to break on the exception (Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings, check the exception) or ignore it. I can live with clicking the Continue button (or F5) a couple of times.

Comment: ... huh? You've misread my answer entirely. The answer is simply that what I want is not currently possible. Yes the comments helped me reach that conclusion but no, that conclusion is not in anybody's comments. That's why I made the answer. Woe is me for putting it plainly for everyone to see.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General > select "Only enable my code (managed only)".

Then use the DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute to tell the debugger that the function is not part of the code.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]
private static bool TestFunc()
{
    try
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

If it still doesn't work please let me know.

Comment: This has the same effect as the `DebuggerHidden` attribute; Visual Studio breaks on the line calling `TestFunc()`.

Comment: @CarlSchmidt Hi, both the sample code you provided and the code I provided to you, it doesn't break when I test it with the console. So my guess is that there is something wrong with your exception settings. Please follow the steps below: Debug=>Windows=>Exception Settings. Right-click all the options below and click Restore Defaults.