# In Visual Studio 2015 DebuggerStepThrough doesn't pass over exceptions anymore?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In earlier versions of Visual Studio you could use the [DebuggerStepThrough] attribute to ignore exception in a special method which for some reason cannot be avoided (network exceptions e.g. or maybe failing parsings). (See this Thread: [Don't stop debugger at THAT exception when it's thrown and caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420390/dont-stop-debugger-at-that-exception-when-its-thrown-and-caught))

Now Visual Studio shows me the exception at the calling function without the attribute even though it's already caught and processed.

Example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExceptionalMethod();
    }
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    static void ExceptionalMethod()         
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("BAM");
        }
        catch 
        { }
    }
```

This code should not stop in VS 2013 or lower. Same behaviour with DebuggerHidden.

Is there a new trick to ignore that very one exception? Without ignoring all exceptions of that type of course?

Comment: Please explain what you mean here. If I enable "stop on all thrown exceptions" on "Common language runtime exceptions", both Visual Studio 2012 and 2015 stops, though they stop in different locations. 2012 stops on the throw-statement but 2015 stops on the outer method call. If I disable the same setting, neither version stops. Please clarify.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 doesn't stop at all for me with the attribute set.

Comment: This was also the way VS2013 RTM behaved, the Connect feedback report [is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800415/regression-debugger-incorrectly-breaks-on-exceptions-caught-in-debuggerstepthrough-code).  Fixed in Update 2.  The debugger team has a pretty unhealthy track-record of incorporating post-release bug fixes back into their main branch.  Nothing we can do about it, I recommend you file a feedback report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft deactivated the feature due to "beneficial performance improvement when debugging .NET code".

In Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 it's possible to turn the feature on/the performance improvement off by changing a registry key.

Enter this into your command line to do that:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\Debugger\Engine /v AlwaysEnableExceptionCallbacksOutsideMyCode /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Source:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/02/12/using-the-debuggernonusercode-attribute-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: This did not make a change on my try.