# Don't stop debugger at THAT exception when its thrown and caught

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I use DebuggerStepThrough to prevent the debugger from halting on exceptions that I intentionally handle as a logical decision (i only do this when an object model leaves me no choice).

Since installing VS 2015 and using 'Break on ALL CLR Exceptions' DebuggerStepThrough no longer works.

Anyone know how I can work around this?

This issue has been discussed elsewhere but I believe it needs updating now that VS 2015 is out:
[Don't stop debugger at THAT exception when it's thrown and caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420390/dont-stop-debugger-at-that-exception-when-its-thrown-and-caught)

-- Edit --

To clarify DebuggerStepThrough does NOT work for me.

It works fine when 'Break on ALL CLR Exceptions' is OFF.

When 'Break on ALL CLR Exceptions' is ON, the debugger stops on the line where I call the method that has DebuggerStepThrough even though the exception is handled in that method. Very annoying!

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741071/in-visual-studio-2015-debuggerstepthrough-doesnt-pass-over-exceptions-anymore

Comment: I am running Update 1. Any thoughts as to whether a setting might be incorrect?

Comment: Have you turned on the "Just My Code" setting in Visual Studio? cause this affects the DebuggerStepThroughAtrribute